# how to send firebase test cloud message with custom data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message) tutorial to send firebase test cloud messages. It works fine, but I want to send test message with custom data. I couldn't find any option in firebase console to do that. And I cannot test custom data by sending messages to all the installs, because my app have been installed over 30k times. So, how can I do that?

Comment: And you can't create another project to play around with so you don't risk disturbing your install base?

Comment: oh.. i didn't think about that... i think i can create a sample project.. thank you for your suggestion..

Comment: Maybe use [`dry_run`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)? But creating a staging playground would be better.